# AngularJs hide div elements for specific path/controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
<html>
<head>
       // additional info here
</head>

<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="contentController">
      <div id="container">

           <div id="id1">
                //content here
           </div>

           <div id="id2">
                //content here
           </div>

           <div id="id3">
                //content here
           </div>

           <div id="page-content">
                <div data-ng-view="">
                     //here will be loaded the other views 
                     //Example: /profile, /login, /register, etc etc)
                </div>
           </div>

      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need is to hide the `divs: id1, id2, id3`  when the user navigates to specific pages like /login or register. For all other pages the `divs: id1, id2, id3` should be visible.

At the moment when the user navigates to `/login` the `divs: id1, id2, id3` content is shown with the login form so I have to hide it somehow.

The `divs: id1, id2, id3` are common for all pages except for `/login`, `/register` and `/forgot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`$locationChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess)** event broadcasted from the $rootScope to check the current route using the `$route` service. The advantage of this methodology, is that navigation through the use of the address bar can still be detected.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/27Jel3zrICyAKlDhEo2J?p=preview)**

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
  .controller('contentController', function($scope, $rootScope, $route) {

    var paths = ['/login', '/register', '/forgot'];

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {

      var $$route = $route.current.$$route;
      $scope.contentVisibility = $$route && paths.indexOf($$route.originalPath) < 0;

    });

  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="contentController">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="id1" ng-show="contentVisibility">
                //content here
           </div>
      <div id="id2" ng-show="contentVisibility">
                //content here
           </div>
      <div id="id3" ng-show="contentVisibility">
                //content here
      </div>
      <div id="page-content">
        <div data-ng-view="">
             //here will be loaded the other views 
             //Example: /profile, /login, /register, etc etc)
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- list of routes bound within the anchor tags -->
      <a ng-repeat="path in [
          '/login', '/register', '/forgot', 
          '/other-route-1', '/other-route-2', '/other-route-3']" 
          ng-href="#{{path}}">{{path}}<br></a>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `data-ng-hide` to hide your contents. however, you have to set the variable at start of your specific controller in order to hide the contents and in other controllers you should set it false to show the contents.

At the beginning of your specific controller:

```
var $scope.contentHide = true;
```

At the beginning of other controllers:

```
var $scope.contentHide = false; 

<div id="id1" data-ng-hide="contentHide">
                //content here
</div>

<div id="id2" data-ng-hide="contentHide">
                //content here
</div>

<div id="id3" data-ng-hide="contentHide">
                //content here
</div>
```

Comment: So that means I don't have to validate or at least care of the url location or make a check what is the current url like: `$scope.contentHide = $location.path() === '/login'` right?

Comment: No, you don't need that

Comment: One more question, what about the controllers, as you can see in the html above, when I go to /login the login view will load within `data-ng-view` and the controller used in /login is declared in the login view. Will that property apply to the elements above the div `data-ng-view` ?

Comment: I'm not sure lets try